# angular resource PUT response lost

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to I get angular to retain data updates returned in the response to a PUT?

I have a basic angular (vsn 1.2.26) RESTful app that successfully retrieves, updates and writes data back to the server.  The server alters the "updateTime" field of the updated record and returns it in the (200) response to the browser.  I can see the updated value in the $resource.save callback function, but I can't figure how to persist it to the $scope beyond the duration of the callback to make it visible in the UI.

```
angular.module('myResources',['ngResource'])
    .factory('Fund',['$resource',function($resource)
        {
        return $resource('http://myhost/xyz/fund/:id'
                        ,{ id: '@guid' }
                        ,{ save: { method: 'PUT' }
                          ,query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false }
                         }
                        );
        }])
...
$scope.selectRecord = function(R)
    {
    ...
    $scope.record = R;
    }

$scope.saveRecordChanges = function()
    {
    ...
    myFundResource.save($scope.record,function(response){
        $scope.record = angular.fromJson(response); // gets refreshed data but doesn't update UI
        console.log("new updateTime=" + $scope.record.updateTime); // correctly displays new value in the log
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me the response before you invoke fromJson? Seems you don't need to convert json to javascrit object manually.

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang here's the response:
Response headers:
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 161
Body:
{ "guid" : "357fad51-62d5-420c-9372-1449817192b8", "fundCode" : "46", "name" : "ABACAB", "system" : "X17", "updateTime" : "2014-11-13T16:27:14" }

Comment: Eh, I mean the response in you myFundResource.save callback; Can you use console.log() to log response in save callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that I was expecting the ng-repeat record list to update - but I wasn't updating the list, only redirecting the $scope.record (current record) pointer to a new object.  I added code to update the record list:

```
myFundResource.save($scope.record,function(response)
    {
    var vIdx = $scope.allRecords.indexOf($scope.record); // allRecords is bound to the UI table via ng-repeat
    $scope.record = response;  // ** $scope.record no longer points to the same object as $scope.allRecords[vIdx] - array is unaware of this change
    $scope.allRecords[vIdx] = $scope.record; // replace array element with new object
    });
```

Thank you to @Tyler.z.yang for your insights and questions that got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your save callback function:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Or you can change you function into:

```
$scope.saveRecordChanges= function(){
    myFundResponse.save($scope.record).$promise.then(function(response){
        $scope.record = response;
    });
};
```

Cuz in angular $promise, it will invoke $asyncEval to call your success or error callback, which means with angular $promise will update the view automatically.

Comment: I found calling $scope.$apply() threw a digest-in-progress error.

Comment: @MichaelLemaire Can you try to use $promise.then ?

Comment: The $promise ran, but still didn't assign the updates to the $scope.  Perhaps this is a sign that I'm doing something in a weird newbie way?  :)

Comment: Can you remove angular.fromJson in $promise.then callback. I already update my answer.

Comment: I've just added more display controls and I think I'm approaching the answer.  I've been expecting to see the change in the record LIST (ng-repeat) from which the record was selected for editing.  When I add a control to specifically show the record.updateTime it DOES update.  Is it possible that by assigning $scope.record I'm simply not updating the list?

Comment: I think if you bind the data to $scope correctly, angular will update the view. Can you post you code to jsfiddle?